# Create Facebook story with facebook sdk for python and Graph API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm a relative beginner to coding. I know how to create normal posts on my page with facebook sdk for python and Graph API.
I'd like to know how to do the same to Create a 'story' for my page.

This is currently the code I have, It's working for me:

```
import facebook as fb

access_token = ""

xfb = fb.GraphAPI(access_token)

xfb.put_photo(open("./123.JPG","rb"), message = "Message here")
```

I've tried to look through the Graph API, but can't figure out how to create a 'Story' through python.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.